# SPLIT_BUNDLE 1555876812: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I'm a publisher, and 2 days ago, i updated my app, but after like 2 hours I received this message(see the photo), and I don't know how to resolve it. I have tried all ways, but I don't understand how to fix it. Can you help me to resolve the problem, please?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Getting "APK 25: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device" since my latest appbundle update and I am not able to identify the problem in my data safety form. Also, my app does not even collect data about other installed apps

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case it complains to apk versions which were in the alpha test and internal test. Although these test are stopped long ago. My curernt version is 900, but those versions are 112 and 350, the versions like from several years ago, may be back then there was some sdk which could access this info but not the current one, anyway I can't update the current one. I will try to fill the form or upload a new version to test and alpha branches, and see what happens. Can't solve this for several days already.

Comment: @tmaihoff I am also facing the same issue. If you resolved it, could you please let me know how you did it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to fill additionally:
App Content->Data Safety, Manage->Next->Next->App activity,Installed apps (select check box) and then fill it on the next step.